# Click Loads multiple videos using YOUTUBE Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, dom-events

I have some thumbnails below the main video container.
I will like when you click on each thumbnail - the associated video loads and start playing
Using the NEW YOUTUBE API IFRAME approach [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Operations)

Your help or direction will be appreciated

[PREVIEW ON JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/Y9j7R/4/)

PREVIEW LINK UPDATED***

Comment: Is the preview supposed to do anything? Because it shows nothing when I try it...

Comment: I'm not getting anything either

Comment: sorry had the wrong version..updated now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9j7R/5/

Run this code on load:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");            //1
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){                         //2
    if(!/#ytplayer/.test(a[i].href)) continue;         //3
    var link = a[i].innerHTML.match(/\/vi\/([^\/]+)/); //4
    if(link) (function(vidId){                         //5
        a[i].onclick = function(){                     //6
            player.loadVideoById(vidId);               //7
        }                                              //8
    })(link[1]);                                       //9
}
```

### Detailed explanation of the code

1. Select all `<a>` (anchor) elements in the document
2. Loop through these anchors using **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**. During each iteration, the "current" anchor is referred through `a[i]`.
3. Check whether the `href` attribute does *not* (`!`) contain "`#ytplayer`" using the **[`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** method of the **[Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)**. If this condition is true (ie: the `href` attribute does not contain "`#ytplayer`"), the **[`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)** statement terminates the current iteration, and jumps to the next anchor.
4. The **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)** property of the current anchor is requested. The **[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method is used to get the video id. The [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\/vi\/([^\/]+)/` means: match a substring which equals *`/vi/<any consecutive non-slash chars>`*, and group `<any consecutive non-slash chars>`.
   When such a substring is found, the `link` variable has a property `1` (one), which holds the value of this group. Otherwise, `link` equals `null`.
5. If the `link` variable is not `null`, an anonymous **[`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)** is created (lines 5-9) and executed (line 9). The first argument of the function will be referenced through *`vidId`* (variable).
6. Assigns a newly created **[`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)** to the `onclick` property of the current anchor. Assigning a function to the `onclick` property will cause the **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)** event handler to be defined.
7. Invokes the **[`loadVideoById`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#loadVideoById)** method of the `player` object (as defined by the [YouTube javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)).
8. 
9. Invokes the function (created at lines 5-9), passing `link[1]` as a first parameter.

### References

- **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** loops and the **[`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)** statement
- Creating and calling **[`functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)** in JavaScript
- **[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** (RegExp).
- **[`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** method of the `RegExp` object
- The **[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** function in conjunction with a Regular expression
- The **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)** property of an element
- The **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)** event handler
- The **[`loadVideoById`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#loadVideoById)** method of the **[YouTube JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)**

### Another interesting answer

- [YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html/7513356#7513356)

Comment: HEY ROB...thanks for your reply. Is there any way you can explain this for loop fully.? I understand most of it, but not all. I'm new to Jquery overall.

Comment: jQuery? What I've shown is pure JavaScript. What part did you not understand?

Comment: THIS:
<code>
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(!/#ytplayer/.test(a[i].href)) continue;
    var link = a[i].innerHTML.match(/\/vi\/([^\/]+)/);
    if(link) (function(vidId){
        a[i].onclick = function(){
            player.loadVideoById(vidId);
        }
    })(link[1]);

Comment: @MIS I've added the explanation of my code at the answer, including references. Do you understand it now?

Comment: Yep Got it thank You Quick Question. What if I want to Get The title for each video when the videos comes up. Do you have any idea how I go about that.



But then i said to myself there must be a way to get it using the DATA API or Player API....still looking into it.

Thanks for any help in advance.




I was going to do something like this :
<code>
if (vidId == 'video_id1'){
   
     $("#titlediv").append("<strong>VIDEO 1</strong>");
  }
</code>