# YouTube API Target (multiple) existing iframe(s)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to understand how to target an existing iframe using the YouTube API (i.e. without constructing an iframe with the script).

As usual, Google does not give enough API examples, but explains that it IS possible, here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do - the video underneath the thumbnail should play. I am almost there, but only the first video plays...

http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/KtbYR/2/

Comment: Wow ok think I've found a solution to my problem, but seems hugely complicated for what should be a simple API - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### TL;DR: DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/5/

`YT_ready`, `getFrameID` and `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` are functions as defined in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536)**. Both methods can be implemented without any preloaded library. In my previous answer, I showed a method to implement the feature for a single frame.

In this answer, I focus on multiple frames.

**HTML example code** (important tags and attributes are capitalized, `<iframe src id>`):

```
<div>
  <img class='thumb' src='http://i2.cdnds.net/11/34/odd_alan_partridge_bio_cover.jpg'>
  <IFRAME ID="frame1" SRC="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>
</div>
<div>
  <img class='thumb' src='http://i2.cdnds.net/11/34/odd_alan_partridge_bio_cover.jpg'>
  <IFRAME ID="frame2" SRC="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code (`YT_ready`, `getFrameID`, `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` and the *YouTube Frame API* script loader are defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536))**

```
var players = {}; //Define a player storage object, to expose methods,
                  //  without having to create a new class instance again.
YT_ready(function() {
    $(".thumb + iframe[id]").each(function() {
        var identifier = this.id;
        var frameID = getFrameID(identifier);
        if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
            players[frameID] = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                events: {
                    "onReady": createYTEvent(frameID, identifier)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

// Returns a function to enable multiple events
function createYTEvent(frameID, identifier) {
    return function (event) {
        var player = players[frameID]; // Set player reference
        var the_div = $('#'+identifier).parent();
        the_div.children('.thumb').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.fadeOut().next().addClass('play');
            if ($this.next().hasClass('play')) {
                player.playVideo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my previous answer, I bound the `onStateChange` event. In this example, I used the `onReady` event, because you want to call the functions only once, at initialization.

This example works as follows:

- The following methods are defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536).

  1. The *YouTube Frame API* is loaded from http://youtube.com/player_api.
  2. When this external script has finished loading, `onYoutubePlayerAPIReady` is called, which in his turn activates all functions as defined using `YT_ready`
- The declaration of the following methods are shown here, but implemented using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536). Explanation based on the example:

  1. Loops through each `<iframe id>` object, which is placed right after `<.. class="thumb">`.
  2. At each frame element, the `id` is retrieved, and stored in the `identifier` variable.
  3. The internal ID of the iframe is retrieved through `getFrameID`. This ensures that the `<iframe>` is properly formatted for the API. *In this example code, the returned ID is equal to `identifier`, because I have already attached an ID to the `<iframe>`.*
  4. When the `<iframe>` exists, and a valid YouTube video, a new player instance is created, and the reference is stored in the `players` object, accessible by key `frameID`.
  5. At the creation of the player instance, a **`onReady`* event is defined. This method will be invoked when the API is fully initialized for the frame.
  6. **`createYTEvent`**
     This method returns a dynamically created function, which adds functionality for separate players. The most relevant parts of the code are:

     ```
     function createYTEvent(frameID, identifier) {
         return function (event) {
             var player = players[frameID]; // Set player reference
             ...
                     player.playVideo();
         }
     }
     ```

     - `frameID` is the ID of the frame, used to enable the *YouTube Frame API*.
     - `identifier` is the ID as defined in `YT_ready`, not necessarily an `<iframe>` element. `getFrameID` will attempt to find the closest matching frame for a given id. That is, it returns the ID of a given `<iframe>` element, or: If the given element is not an `<iframe>`, the function looks for a child which is a `<iframe>`, and returns the ID of this frame. If the frame does not exists, the function will postfix the given ID by `-frame`.
     - players[playerID]` refers to the initialized player instance.

### Make sure that you *also* check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536), because the core functionality of this answer is based on that.

[Other YouTube Frame API answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A938089+[youtube-api]&submit=search). In these answers, I showed various implementations of the YouTube Frame/JavaScript API.

Comment: Demo for your question. http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/3/ I have to go now, so I will not be able to respond for the next hours.

Comment: Thanks Rob, really impressed with your coding! Incidentally - why is it a security measure to absolutely position an image in front of a video? Curious.

Comment: @SparrwHawk One could position a (partially) transparent element/image in front of a third-party frame, and trick a user in sharing unwanted information. That's a huge potential security issue.

Comment: ok fair enough, but there is no punishment in terms of SEO, etc. though? It's just a moral consideration, right?

Comment: @SparrwHawk Most modern browsers disallow (partially) invisible elements from overlapping a frame. It's not a punishment in terms of SEO or moral, but in terms of accessibility. The button would never be clickable, because the iframe is over it. However: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865904/jquery-fade-in-youtube-iframe-embed/7866323#7866323) + demo at the answer.

Comment: Note that I tried `<iframe ... />` which does *not* work (Chrome, Safari, iOS), `<iframe ...></iframe>` does work though.

Comment: Thanks @RobW for this wonderful solution, this has saved me a whole day from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Don't forget the ?enablejsapi=1 in the source of the video