# Pause youtube video when soundcloud audio is playing

Tags: youtube-api

How to pause a youtube video when soundcloud audio paying and vise versa

```
<span class="soundcloud_embed" id="soundcloud_post_312">
  <iframe id="ui-id-1" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" 
     frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
     url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/163100334&amp;
     color=%23ff5500&amp;
     auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;
     show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&amp;
     visual=true">
  </iframe>

</span>

<span class="youtube_embed" id="youtube_post_309">
 <iframe id="ui-id-2" width="560"height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/
    embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" gesture="media" 
    allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</span>
```

I've found the source at this link
[Pause Youtube embed when playing Soundcloud embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117605/pause-youtube-embed-when-playing-soundcloud-embed)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpq9n7ht/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to control the player, you need [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your
>   website and control the player using JavaScript.

Read through the documentation to get started. There is [starter guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) that will help you how to use the API. Codes are also available as your reference depending on the functions that you want to use.

For the [requirements](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements), remember this.

> The user's browser must support the HTML5 postMessage feature. Most
>   modern browsers support postMessage, though Internet Explorer 7 does
>   not support it.