# Youtube iframe API, subscribing to events

Tags: javascript, events, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

[YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html/7513356#7513356)

How do I subscribe to events here? I would like to listen for video finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my function as defined at **this answer: [Listening for Youtube Event in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-jquery/7988536#7988536)**.

In your case, implement the core functions as shown below (**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2w5x/**)

```
// Core functions defined at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7988536#7988536
var player;
YT_ready(function(){
    var frameID = getFrameID("YOUR-frame-or-container-ID-here");
    if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
        player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
            events: {
                "onStateChange": function(event){
                    if(event.data == "0") {
                        //The video has finished
                        alert("The video has finished!");
                        //Do something, example: play again
                        player.playVideo();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```