# Video play at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to make so that the video played at the same time on two computers ?

If the video lagged on one side, then the other must wait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube videos in sync on multiple clients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423091/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-sync-on-multiple-clients)

Comment: Yes. Now where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of where each user is in the video. To get the current position:

```
var currentPos = document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime;
```

And post them to your server for each user's session. Then, keep comparing the two times and if one gets over a few seconds ahead, send a pause command to the one that is ahead.

The specifics of how to do this will depend strongly on your server-side setup and how you're maintaining sessions for users.

Comment: thanks, also i find website https://www.watch2gether.com/, i'll try make same system.