# How to stop embedded Youtube videos from playing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

SoundCloud players have a default functionality where when a user starts a player, it automatically pauses all others that are currently playing. (example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vx6hM/).

I'm trying to recreate this with embedded youtube videos that are added dynamically via the normal embed code.

Using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513356/938089
and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988536/1470827

I'm able to get this far:

```
function chain(){

$('.post').each(function(){
    var player_id = $(this).children('iframe').attr("id");
    var other_player_id = $(this).siblings().children('iframe').attr("id");

    player = new YT.Player( player_id, { 

        events:
            {      
            'onStateChange': function (event) 
                {

                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) 
                    { callPlayer( other_player_id , 'pauseVideo' );
                     alert('Trying to pause: ' + other_player_id);
                    }            

                }
            }        
    });

});

}
```

**Here's a JS Bin with it half working: http://jsbin.com/oxoyes/2/edit**

Currently, its only calling one of the players. I need it to pause ALL of the other players except the playing one.

Also, any tips on how to clean this up and/or do it differently/better are welcome. I'm still very new to javascript so I'm not even sure I'm going about it the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a blog post that details a full working example of responding to various Youtube player API events: http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/08/21/triggering-a-youtube-video-from-clicking-a-button-image-and-replacing-when-ended/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll only have at most one player playing at a given time. Instead of trying to pause all that are playing, think of it as trying to pause the one playing. Of course, none could be playing. Given this, take a look at the following code. You maintain a single outer scope variable and pause that when necessary, while setting it to the player you just started playing thereafter.

```
var playerCurrentlyPlaying = null;
function chain(){       
    $('.post').each(function(){
        var player_id = $(this).children('iframe').attr("id");
        player = new YT.Player( player_id, { 
            events:
                {      
                'onStateChange': function (event) 
                    {

                    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) 
                        { 
                          if(playerCurrentlyPlaying != null && 
                          playerCurrentlyPlaying != player_id)
                          callPlayer( playerCurrentlyPlaying , 'pauseVideo' );
                          playerCurrentlyPlaying = player_id;

                        }            

                    }
                }        
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might achieve your solution

```
var players=[];
 function chain(id){


    var player_id = $('#player'+id).attr('id');


   players[id]=new YT.Player( player_id, { 

        events:
            {      
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }

    });

 }

 function onPlayerStateChange(event){


  var playerid=$(event.target).attr('id');

  if(event.data!=-1 && event.data!=5){

      for(i=1;i<players.length;i++){

       if(playerid!=i){


      players[i].stopVideo();
       }

     }


   }
}
```

the problem with your previous code was that you where using each in call function so it might execute 3*3 times so creating 9 instances of the player.So what i have done is that i am storing each instance in an array.

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/oxoyes/11/edit

Answer (score 0):

I tried the way posted by cbayram and found it to have spotty success.
I preferred fuzionpro's way but had to correct a few problems w/ it and I came up w/ the following, which works well and includes console.logs so you can see whats happening.
Probably combining ytPlayers and ytPlayerStates below would make it more efficient.

```
// load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytPlayers = new Array();
var ytPlayerStates = new Array();

window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function()
{
    jQuery('.video-container>iframe').each(function(index)
    {
        var iframeID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        ytPlayerStates[iframeID] = -1;

        (function (iframeID) {
            ytPlayers.push(new YT.Player(iframeID, { 
                events:
                {      
                    'onStateChange' : function (event) 
                    {
                        console.log(iframeID+' '+event.data);

                        if (event.data == 1)
                        {
                            ytPlayerStates[iframeID] = 1;
                            for (var key in ytPlayerStates)
                            {
                                if (key != iframeID)
                                {
                                    if (ytPlayerStates[key] == 1 || ytPlayerStates[key] == 3)
                                    {
                                        ytPlayerStates[key] = 2;
                                        callPlayer(key, 'pauseVideo')
                                    }
                                }
                                console.log(key+' : '+ytPlayerStates[key]);
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        })(iframeID); 
    });
}
```