# Interface with existing Ooyala iframe embed via JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ooyala

I'm embedding a Ooyala player via a fairly standard `iframe` embed:

```
 <iframe id="video-1" src="http://www.flotrack.org/embed/MzU3NzQwODE1?related=0&autoplay=false" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to utilize Ooyala's JavaScript API to communicate with an `iframe` that is already on the page? I'd rather not replace a `div` with a player as the [API example shows](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_createplayers.html). I am embedding videos from an Ooyala account I do not own. I'd like to accomplish something along the lines of the following:

```
player = OO.Player.create('video-1');
player.play()
```

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-javascript-or-jquery/7988536), I've been able to accomplish this for a YouTube embed with [YouTube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) as long as the embed `src` attribute includes the parameter `enablejsapi=1`.

Can I do the same with an Ooyala iframe embed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is not supported, check out our doc on iFrame.
http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_iframe_nonwindows.html

You can embed with IFRAME, but the interaction via JS is not possible.

BTW, we have a support community: http://community.ooyala.com/  Check it out when you have technical questions. :-)

Cheers,
Thomas