# using YouTube iFrame API within jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a page in which clicking a link opens a lightbox and embeds a YouTube video in an `<iframe>`. The lightbox and `<iframe>` markup are generate on the fly by [Lity](https://github.com/jsor/lity).

Following the example right out of the documentation, where the `<iframe>` is hard-coded into the page, it works as expected.

```
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"
        width="640" height="360"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border: solid 4px #37474F">
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log('api ready');
    player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
  }
  function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
      color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
      color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
      color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
    }
    if (color) {
      document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = color;
    }
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
  }
</script>
```

**[See this Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/wvMrjQV?editors=1111)**

I'm trying to modify it to work with a dynamically generated `<iframe>` (which is how Lity handles YouTube videos). I can see that the YouTube API script is being added to the page, but the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` does not ever seem to be called, which according to documentation is supposed to fire as soon as API script loads.

**HTML (to open lightbox)**

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" class="lity" data-lity>open</a>
```

**JavaScript (fires after lightbox object is available in DOM)**

```
$(document).on("lity:ready", function (event, instance) {
  console.log("Lightbox ready");
  $(".lity-youtube iframe").attr("id", "x");
   if ($("iframe#x").length) {
    console.log("ID added to <iframe>");
  } else {
    console.log("ID NOT added to <iframe>");
  }

  
  var tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.id = "iframe-demo";
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  if ($("#iframe-demo").length) {
    console.log("api script added");
  } else {
    console.log("api script NOT added");
  }

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("api ready");
    player = new YT.Player("x", {
      events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log("player ready");
    document.getElementById("x").style.borderColor = "#FF6D00";
  }
  function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
      color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
      color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
      color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
    }
    if (color) {
      document.getElementById("x").style.borderColor = color;
    }
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log('state change');
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
  }
});
```

**[See this Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/qBbPozq).**

I tried pulling everything out of the `lity:ready` event handler with the same results....

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

### **EDIT/UPDATE**

I tried running `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` as a deferred object

```
 var YTdeferred = $.Deferred();
 window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
   YTdeferred.resolve(window.YT);
 };
```

and using it in the callback

```
var player;
YTdeferred.done(function (YT) {
  console.log("api ready");
  player = new YT.Player("x", {
    events: {
      //onReady: onPlayerReady,
      //onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
      onReady: function () {
        console.log("player ready from ananonymous");
      },
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  console.log(player);
});
```

Now the `YT.Player` object is created (presumably on the `iframe` created by `lity`), but neither of the events (`onReady` and `onStateChange`) seem to be triggering. Also, it doesn't have access to any of the methods or properties that it should:

```
player.playVideo()
```

produces an error: player.playVideo is not a function`

Still stumped.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/qBbPozq)

### **ANOTHER EDIT/UPDATE**

Now I'm very confused because i created a version that replicates what `lity` does (I think) and the events (`onReady` and `onStateChange`) do in fact fire as expected.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/GRoMPRx)

### **Solution to a STUPID mistake**

I can' believe I beat my head into the wall over this for so long... G'AAAAAAH!!

**It's definitely a `lity` thing**

When `lity` receives an argument (YouTube URL) formatted like

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX

or

> http://youtu.be/XXXXXXXXX

it converts it to

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX?autoplay=1

If you try to pass query string arguments to to a similarly formatted URL (such as: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX?enablejsapi=1` (which is required for the API calls to work), it URLencodes the `?enablejsapi=1` and adds it to the end of the converted URL, so you get:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX?autoplay=1&%3Fenablejsapi=1

As a result the `enablejsapi=1` is never read in and therefore the `YT.Player` is never attached to the `<iframe>` DOM element.

** **SOLUTION** ** 
Pass the URL to `lity` in a format that passes the video ID as a query string argument (and append `enablejsapi=1`):

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX&enablejsapi=1

`lity` will now keep your argument(s) intact and convert to

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1

Now the `YT.Player` call can read `enablejsapi=1` and properly attach to the `<iframe>` element, and all is good in the universe.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJU-tBquzcM&enablejsapi=1" class="lity" data-lity>open lightbox with video</a>
```

**[Final Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/mdVqbge)**

.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-javascript-or-jquery offers a very robust solution to the general challenge of being able to listen for events with a pre-existing `<iframe>`. **With `lity`** It still only works when you pass the URL in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "lity:ready" event is not fired in my case.
I changed

`$(document).on("lity:ready", function (event, instance) {`

to

`$(document).ready(function (event, instance) {`

using the jQuery ready event.

And most important, the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` must be global (on window scope) to be detected by the youtube iFrame API (actually it was created inside an anonymous `function()` ). So I changed

`function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {`

to

`window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady=function() {`

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/xxZXyra)

**EDIT**:

To work on a global context inside an anonymous function. Other local functions created and referenced (`onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerStateChange`) must be declared in the global context using the window object.

```
window.onPlayerReady=function(event) {
    console.log("player ready");
    document.getElementById("x").style.borderColor = "#FF6D00";
 }
 window.changeBorderColor=function(playerStatus) {
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
      color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
      color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
      color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
      color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
      color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
    }
    if (color) {
      document.getElementById("x").style.borderColor = color;
    }
 }
 window.onPlayerStateChange=function(event) {
    console.log('state change');
    changeBorderColor(event.data);
 }
```

Comment: the `lity:ready` event does not fire until you click the "open" text link. It has to wait until then because the `iframe` is not created until then... and the `iframe` is what is referenced when the player object is created (`player = new YT.Player("x",...` - `x` is the `ID` of the `iframe`. But yes `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady=function() {` gets the function to fire and thus the player created, but now I can't get either of the callbacks (`onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerStateChange`) to fire.

Comment: @Daveh0 any update on this ?

I've the same problem. My code works in my local enviroment i.e both the events are getting called but in Live the same code doesn't work.

Comment: I've added some additional changes, to make the callbacks available in the global context.

Comment: @SohaibAhmad - see my updates in OP - let me know if that doesn't help. but also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988476/listening-for-youtube-event-in-javascript-or-jquery for a very robust, working solution