# Is there any way to check if user already subscribed to my youtube channel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on a script , and i need to check if a user has already subscribed to my youtube channel, is there any API call or any script to check if the user already subscribed or not ? 
Any type of help/hint will be heartly appreciated :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885126/youtube-iframe-api-subscribing-to-events might help mate! cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,youtube Api can help you,follow this link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Saving_and_collecting_videos

But I'm not sure it need user authorization or not.

Sorry,wrong link,follow this:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieving_subscriptions

the api just like

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/subscriptions?v=2
```

You can get a user's subscriptions,then you can check your channel is in it or not.
This request does not require authentication.

Comment: Are you sure we can check if the user subscribed or not with the above API. Please elaborate more. Thanks

Comment: The problem now is how you would get the yt username of a visitor. that will require authentication. or maybe you can use his/her gmail address