# jQuery - Tab with videos... how do I get videos to stop playing when I switch between tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am new to jQuery, and I managed to create a tab interface. I want each section of my tab to have a YouTube video. However, when I click play on the video that is on tab 1 for example, and then switch to tab 2, the video on tab 1 still keeps on playing. Please see the entire code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwfFE/3/

I would greatly appreciate any help on how to stop the video once the user clicks on other tabs.

Also, when I run this on my Android, flash enabled phone, the videos don't seem to play. Any idea of what I need to do to fix? Or do I need to fix anything else to make code browser compatible?

Comment: See: [video won't stop when div is hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/video-wont-stop-when-div-is-hidden/8668741#8668741).

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you so much. I am really new to JavaScript in general - so would appreciate insight as to how to implement this exactly in my code. Thank you!

Comment: If you're new to JavaScript, and willing to learn it, my best advice is: **Bury jQuery**, and learn the [basics of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) first. *Response to question*: An easier implementation of the YouTube API can be found here: **[Youtube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html#7513356)**.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you very much. I will definitely check it out. What's Bury jQuery? Is that a book? Where do I find it. Also - I appreciate the link... I'll try to figure it out and will let you know if I run into issues.

Comment: By "bury jQuery", I mean that you'd better *not* use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), because it does not teach you how to write JavaScript code. *When you've mastered jQuery, you still do not know much about JavaScript.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwfFE/5/

I simply put all your URL's in an array. When the user decides to leave the tab, I clear the `src` of the `iframe` so that the video "stops" playing.

The first time your `currentTab` variable is still empty though, so I retrieve it by looking at which `<li>` has its class set to `active`. From this `<li>` I take the link and set the `currentTab` variable to its `href`.

```
if (currentTab == '') {
   //Find current tab:
   currentTab = $('#tabs ul li.active').find('a').attr('href');
}

//Stop playing video:
if (currentTab != '')
   $('div#' + currentTab).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
```

When he gets back to any tab, you should not forget to set the `src` back though, else your iFrame will be empty. It's what I do here:

```
var index = $(this).attr('id');
$('div#' + currentTab).find('iframe').attr('src', urls[index]);
```

This code can still be optimized though to reduce the flickering. An easy way to do this is by setting a function on the `load` trigger of the `iframe`'s. This way you know when the video has been successfully set and it is then that you want to show the tab to the user.

Comment: Jules, you are absolutely amazing. THANK YOU THANK YOU so much. I've been spending hours trying to figure this out. REALLY REALLY REALLY appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad it helped. Sometimes all it takes is a little bit of creativity... ;-)

Comment: Hi Jules - I hope all is well. If you don't mind, I have a follow up question for you about this code. Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169305

Comment: thanks for the awesome solution, just 1 question:

How do I 'unrandomized' the 1st-shown tab? Always load 1st tab and content when page load.

Comment: @yiyong The random tab is generated through:
`var index = Math.floor($tabs.length * Math.random()); $tabs.eq(index).show();
`So you could just replace this with $tabs.eq(0).show();
Btw, please upvote the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Note, with more recent versions of jQuery (1.10.2) this script error's out with "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"

Comment: can you add to this solution a Vimeo video ?. can you add arrows to the sides ?  @Jules

Answer (score 2):

Without using any special targeting of iframe or video ids, here's how I stop any playing movie when selecting a different tab. Uses the native bootstrap tab events:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var iframe = $(e.relatedTarget.hash).find('iframe'); 
    var src = iframe.attr('src');
    iframe.attr('src', '');
    iframe.attr('src', src);
s});
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Super helpful and easy snippet.