# trigger play youtube video without api

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have a hidden iframe and use `display:block` to reveal it when user click on the thumbnail.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cGEb-q5JMU0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I also use `autoplay=1` so the user doesn't have to click to start the video. The problem is that the video is playing in the background even though it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteVideo()
{
document.getElementById('VideoPlayer').src='';
}

function LoadVideo()
{
document.getElementById('VideoPlayer').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WHAT,EVER,YOUTUBE,VIDEO,YOU,WHANT';
}
</script>

<body>

<p onclick="LoadVideo()">LOAD VIDEO</P>
<p onclick="deleteVideo()">CLOSE</P>

<iframe id="VideoPlayer" width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/WHAT,EVER,YOUTUBE,VIDEO,YOU,HAVE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</boby>
```

more info from 
[How to pause a YouTube player when hiding the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe)