# Slick slider - Pause a YouTube clip when slider goes to next frame

Tags: jquery, youtube, slider

I’m using slick slider as a multiple gallery slider and one of the items is a YouTube clip. Everything works great, except if a user clicks on the next or previous slide the video keeps playing. I can’t seem to find any documentation on how to automatically pause or stop a YouTube clip when it’s out of frame.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm using slick v1.5.9 and to solve this, I'm currently using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) `.each` to loop through all the iframes and ask each of the iframe to stop playing after slick slider's `afterChange` event was triggered.

**How to stop an iframe :**

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe) to know how to stop/pause an youtube iframe.

**Slick Slider's `afterChange` event :**

You can go to slick-slider's github to know more about its [events/settings](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

**Below is my codes for reference :**

```
$('.hero-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    //init code goes here
}).on('afterChange',function(e,o){
    //on change slide = do action
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        $(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');    
    });
}).slick();
```

*p/s: remember your youtube iframe's parameter's enablejsapi=1 :*

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?autoplay=0&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```