# Get reference to youtube playlist

Tags: javascript, youtube, jsfiddle, playlist, jsapi

I can't get reference to **YouTube** playlist video.

This doesn't work **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bf7zQ/43/)**

I don't even know its real to enable jsapi in playlist?

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('movie_player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("hey Im ready");
//do whatever you want here. Like, player.playVideo();

}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
  console.log("my state changed");
}
```

Comment: what exactly you're trying to do with the youtube playlist?

Comment: I want to stop video when I want, for example, every 10 minutes and do some functions, then continue to play video. I think I need to get object from playing video in playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below code can help you get started, cos I didn't understood correctly what you're trying to achieve. But I understood that you need to play and pause the video. So below is the code which I used somewhere in my project-

```
function toggleVideo(state) {
        if(state == 'pause'){
            document.getElementById('movie_player').contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('movie_player').contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I have completely understood now, below are the steps how you can achieve this-

1) Get Json data for the playlist using the code below-

```
var playlistId = 'PL1HIp83QRJHRbmJl0sS0CLOuIKCBCB76L';
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+ playlistId +'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
// save json data of the playlist
}).error(function() { alert("404 Error"); });
```

See the XML format in the below url, you can get the same data in JSON format by using "&alt=jsonc" in the API url-
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_a_playlist

2) Create two iframes or containers in which you need to keep two youtube players. First one will be the player which you should pause after each 10 minutes or so and when paused you should hide the first container. The second instance should hold the player which should have the second video which should play till completed, on complete hide this container and again show the first container.

See this post on how to play and pause youtube videos- [How to pause a YouTube player when hiding the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe)

3) After each 10 minutes or so, get the next video link and details from the JSON data of the playlist and link it to the second container pausing & hiding the first one and playing & showing the second one.

I hope in this way you can achieve what you require.

Comment: I tried it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50w9s8ms/)  It doesn't work.
I need to stop video no matter what video it is in playlist. Just click "Stop video" and any playing video stops. Is it real?

Comment: But for real reason, I want that video stops every 10 minutes, it shows another video under the previous video. Ok, for example it does so.

Then when the second video is finished, close it. Then play first video with time that it was stopped.

Comment: @slokerantonov please see my updated answer, this should put you up on track

Comment: @slokerantonov Please accept the solution as answer if this helped you, so that others may also benefit if they have same requirements