# Stop Youtube player in IE7 (using Rob W solution)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html/7513356#7513356) made by [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) and everything works fine except for IE7.

Here it is the [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/vYb72/1/). I've also tried importing [this](http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js) to enable JSON on IE, but it still doesn't work on IE7.

There is a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to solve this problem (except for upgrading browser), because IE7 does not support the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) method. This method is required, because it's the only way to communicate with the embedded YouTube frame.

`postMessage` on frames is supported requires IE8+. All of the other modern browsers [have full support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) for the `postMessage` method.