# Youtube API not loading in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have this test slider http://jsfiddle.net/dUyLY/2/

In Chrome it works nice, but in firefox and safari it bugs out when the animation is done.
In the scripts file I check after each animation if the current visible element is the youtube player, if so play the video. And when leaving the slide pause it.

I get this error in console `player.pauseVideo is not a function`

Anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: Please put the code in your question / http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://pastebin.com/. Otherwise, the Q&A will be less helpful to future readers once you update the external page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're deferring the definition of `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`. For this reason, it's likely that the YouTube API finishes before `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` is defined. In that case, your code will fail.

To solve the problem, check whether the API is ready at run-time.

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: 'bpOR_HuHRNs',
    });
};
if (window.YT) {
    // Apparently, the API was ready before this script was executed.
    // Manually invoke the function
    onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
}
```

Note. For simple one-way functions, such as `player.playVideo()` and `player.pauseVideo()`, I recommend to use this simple function, which is not as bloated as the documented YouTube API. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513356/938089?youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html).

Here's a the updated part of your page, using the `callPlayer` function from my other answer instead of the YouTube API: http://jsfiddle.net/ryyCZ/

```
<div id="player">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bpOR_HuHRNs?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
</div>

if ($(".slides_control > div:visible #player").length == 1) {
    callPlayer("player","playVideo");
} else {
    callPlayer("player", "pauseVideo");
}
```

Comment: @halliewuud I can't reproduce your issue. I've implemented `callPlayer`, and it should work (because it automatically queues the API calls when the player does not exist yet). Demo included in answer, http://jsfiddle.net/ryyCZ/show/

Comment: Rob, I updated the question with a proper jsfiddle. Your example does not autoplay and and pause when coming to or leaving the player.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUyLY/2/

Comment: @halliewuud I've successfully tested it in Firefox 13.0.1. In Safari 5.1.7, playback works unless using your jQuery plugin. Weird...

Comment: @halliewuud It works fine here, in Chrome 18.0. Please show some efforts by offering a proper bug report: Version number, test location (locally? When using the `file:` protocol, for example, the YT API does not work, regardless of the wrapper). EDIT: This demo has **successfully been *tested*** in Chrome 18, Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 13.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/ryyCZ/1/. If anything does not work, test again with a clean browser profile.