# TypeError: when deleting/adding iframes via AJAX

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to debug this error, and could use some suggestions:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.a.contentWindow.postMessage')
www-widgetapi-vflsofjNm.js:19
```

Right now this is happening in Safari Version 6.0.2 (7536.26.17). Basic process is this:

I have a page with a container - I load the content into this container with jQuery's $.get():

```
<div id="container">
<iframe id="player1"><iframe id="player2"><iframe id="player3">
</div>
```

I am able to use the iFrame API to stop any of the videos in the container.

```
var player1 = new YT.Player('player1');
console.dir(player1);
player1.stopVideo();
-> no error, video stops
```

I then load different content into a new container:

```
<div id="container">
<iframe><iframe><iframe>
</div>
<div id="anothercontainer"></div>
```

and remove the container holding the iframes:

```
<div id="anothercontainer"></div>
```

I then re-add the iframes (same ID's) and remove the other container:

```
<div id="container">
<iframe id="player1"><iframe id="player2"><iframe id="player3">
</div>
```

After loading the iframe's into the container (the second time around) with the new iframes, I call the YT JS again:

```
var player1 = new YT.Player('player1');
console.dir(player1);
player1.stopVideo();
-> no error, video stops
```

console.dir(player1) displays an object, but when I call player1.stopVideo(), I get the error as mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm really not clear on what your code is doing, as I don't think those snippets you posted are complete/accurate. Could you put together a jsfiddle.net or something else that demonstrates the behavior in a "live" web page?

Comment: Will do - it will take a little bit of work to accomplish. I don't think my example was worded quite well. A series of pictures would probably have made more sense (as odd as that sounds!).

Comment: I started to play around with a Fiddle... but I don't think this will be 'easy' to replicate. Rather... I'm going to strip out any content from my current implementation and post a link.

Comment: I decided not to use the API - I found this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html

Comment: Furthermore, I created a simple page showing what I am doing: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jparisea/pb/transition/three.html -> the only working controls on this page are the top arrows, the video carousel is on slide 11. The intent is to pause the video when someone switches videos on that page. This is just a subset of code (I stripped out a bunch of code): it demonstrates what I was trying to explain above (and failed to do).