# Get user skipped to video which one's arrow is clicked

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

My purpose is getting user skipped to the video which one's red arrow is clicked on this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CDNm3/3/)**

I have tried function `ytplayer_render_playlist( )` but it didn't work. What change i should do on demo to skip video which one's red arrow is clicked?

```
  function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {
      var a = getElementById("trackArrow");
      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
          };
        }
      )( i );

    }
  }
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle almost kills my browser. Anyway, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html

Comment: It must be an instant problem. Because fiddle works on mine without any sweating.