# How to stop video from playing in an <iframe> when switch tabs in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-ui-tabs

I am new to jquery - if someone can could help please!

I have this jquery on my html page that has two tabs
Tab1 has text and image
Tab2 has video in an iframe.
How can I stop the video playing when I switch tabs and the video is blank box until i refresh the page or drag the video cursor to the start.

The script on the page:

```
<script>  $(function() {    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();  }); </script>
```

The div:

```
<div id="tabs">  
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Project Description</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Video</a></li>
</ul>
```

The html

```
<div id="tabs-1">  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.....</p>
    <div id="tabs-2"> <iframe src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/xxxxxxx?controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&endVideoBehavior=reset&fullscreenButton=false&playerColor=005293&hidden code xxxxxxx&version=v1&videoHeight=360&videoWidth=640&volumeControl=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" width="600" height="386"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control an iframe's content... that's not allowed under the cross-domain-policy

Comment: @ Solorzano Jose Thank you!
what is the other way around this if I cannot control iframe? Can I make changes in the iframe perhaps that helps the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html/7513356#7513356