# Youtube iframe API fails to post message

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

For awhile now, a piece of javascript I wrote which listens to youtube actions on a certain page worked wonderfully. I am using Youtube's iframe js api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference . 
But one recent content addition, a specific youtube video, the tracking wouldn't work. The events won't fire at all.

In the console, I noticed this post message error:

`Unable to post message to http://youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://www.youtube.com.`

So nothing with my own code helped. Some questions here on stackoverflow suggested this is an issue with initiating `new YT.player` too soon, so I tried a whole bunch of things like loading the yt js api file on `window` load and only apply the api after, but that didn't seem to do any good either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me over an hour, but the answer was right in front of me. It's actually pretty self explained: **You cannot use youtube's js api to track an iframe video without `www`**. I don't know why, it certainly does not say so in their documentation.

I tested this a few times and confirmed, as of now, tracking an iframe with the source `www.youtube.com/embed/0GN2kpBoFs4` would work wonderfully while tracking `youtube.com/embed/0GN2kpBoFs4` will throw:

`Unable to post message to http://youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://www.youtube.com.`

The confusing part of course is that both the video load and play fine. It's only the API which is not working properly.

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8tkgW/ (Tested on chrome / mountain lion)

Btw, while writing this answer I came across [YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html) - notice this guy's fiddle. He wrote his own youtube iframe implementation (wow!). If you change the iframe source address in the fiddle to one without `www`, it *will work*. This only means youtube writes bad js. Bad bad bad!

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is 3 years old, but for those who are still searching for an answer:

Add this script and everything works fine:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

I've had the same problem with jwplayer and fixed it with that script.

Comment: Thank you, tried lots of stuff including 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. But only this helped.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add it to the whitelist:

```
<!-- Add the whitelist plugin -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="*"/>

<!-- White list https access to Youtube -->
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

## The youtube api documentation recommend to load the api like this

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://youtube.com/iframe_api";
tag.id = "youtubeScript";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

## But getting this error:
Unable to post message to http://youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://www.youtube.com

Here is the best solution I found from [a now-dead site]:

So add this first at the top before calling the Api

```
if (!window['YT']) {var YT = {loading: 0,loaded: 0};}
if (!window['YTConfig']) {var YTConfig = {'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'};}
if (!YT.loading) {YT.loading = 1;(function(){var l = [];YT.ready = function(f) {if (YT.loaded) {f();} 
else 
{l.push(f);}};
window.onYTReady = function() {YT.loaded = 1;for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {try {l[i]();} catch (e) {}}};
YT.setConfig = function(c) {for (var k in c) {if (c.hasOwnProperty(k)) {YTConfig[k] = c[k];}}};
var a = document.createElement('script');
a.type = 'text/javascript';
a.id = 'www-widgetapi-script';
a.src = 'https:' + '//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflumC9r0/www-widgetapi.js';
a.async = true;
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);})();}
```

//===========THEN=============================

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady () {// do stuff here}
```