# Youtube iframes in Bootstrap Carousel - stop video on slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, youtube-api, carousel

I have a bunch of Carousels on a page, each with a mix of videos and images.  I'd like to stop  Youtube videos from playing when the user exits a video by clicking one of the carousel controls (left or right).

I'd like to be able to detect when the user clicks the controls, create a player based on the current video that was playing, and turn that video off.  In the other examples I've seen, the players were declared in the onYoutubeIframeAPIReady function, but I thought it would be better not to dynamically create players for every video on the page.  Right now, I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<T> has no method 'stopVideo'
```

when I click the carousel controls.  However, if I type

```
player.stopVideo();
```

in the Chrome javascript console, it works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  <script>
  var youtubeReady = false;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    youtubeReady = true;
  }

  $('.carousel').on('slide', function(){
    if(youtubeReady){
      console.log("setting player");
      var iframeID = $(this).find('.active').find('iframe').attr("id");
      player = new YT.Player(iframeID); 
      player.stopVideo(); 
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Example carousel:

```
<div class="mainPhoto carousel slide 523" id="carousel-523">
          <div class="carousel-inner 523">
          <div class="item active">
             <div class="flex-video">
                 <a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4pEqbs0ISaw?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1" rel="gallery 523" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
                     <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4pEqbs0ISaw?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1" id="1188">
                     </iframe>
                 </a>
             </div>
         </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a class="fancybox" href="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/image_path/1189/2013-07-05_19.47.55.jpg" rel="gallery 523" data-fancybox-type="image">
                 <img alt="Preview_2013-07-05_19.47.55" id="1189" src="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/image_path/1189/preview_2013-07-05_19.47.55.jpg" width="100%">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-523" data-slide="prev" style="display: none;">‹</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-523" data-slide="next" style="display: none;">›</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the callPlayer function here (which didn't require using the youtube API at all):

[YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html)