# Cannot get Youtube video to stop when using Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, youtube-api

I am using bootstrap's carousel to display YouTube video's, but when I click the next or previous button I want the video to pause. However I keep getting `player.stopVideo is not a function`. I am calling the function onclick on line 34 and 38. And the actual function in the JS file is on line 17. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/mrwadepro/qcqpgobw/1/

Comment: Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514403/youtube-iframes-in-bootstrap-carousel-stop-video-on-slide), it might be helpful. The user ended using the `function callPlayer` as pointed out in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html).