# Playing YouTube videos from embedded player

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api, httprequest

I am trying to play YouTube videos from a chrome extension and I get `error code 150` frequently, specifically from videos that are from outside my country. I use `Youtube Data API v3` to retrieve videos with the following parameters:

`part=id&type=video&order=relevance&safeSearch=strict&videoSyndicated=true&maxResults=1&videoEmbeddable=true`

However, I often get videos that throw error code 150 when played from my embedded player.
One example is the following video:

[Turn down for what](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXd9MPXb6Vs)

when played from an embedded player, it throws error 150, and the error message shown in the iframe is

> the video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites.

I try the same video with the same embedded iframe player in [youtube Player demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) website hosted on `developers.google.com`, and it plays without the error code.

Therefore, I suspect the above error happens because I am trying to play the video **from chrome extension**, not because I am playing it from an embedded player. When I play it from the webpage hosted on my local machine (ex: file:///home/testing.page.html), I get the same error message.

To resolve the issue, I attempted to make YouTube think that I was a normal webpage instead of a chrome extension. By using `chrome.webRequest`, I added a referer information to the request header.

`{ name: 'Referer', value: "https://www.youtube.com" }`

Even after the requestHeader was fixed, the error remained. I assume it's because there's `origin` property attached to youtube iframe player that specifies where the embedded player is from, regardless of the requestHeader.

My objective is either to find videos that are absolutely playable, or play videos that are only playable from a webpage (can't be played from chrome extension).

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

*Extra information*

My iframe is initialized like below:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?
enablejsapi=1&origin=chrome-extension:\\<my_extension_id>" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Try forward slashes instead of backward slashes (`//`). If that doesn't work, try to use a wildcard (`origin=*`).

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for looking into it. I tried them both and if origin is set to anything other than posted, the player object is broken; it doesn't have all the functions and the necessary events (ex: onPlayerReady) do not fire in chrome extension.

Comment: Could you show your code, and paste the request headers for all relevant requests?

Comment: The relevant code: http://pastebin.com/nLnNwBer

Comment: request header: http://pastebin.com/WuuSnVca

Comment: 1. Although not a problem in this case: You're not modifying the "Referer" request header when it already exists (in the `$.grep` function, you need to set `headers.value = customheader;`) 2. To replace the headers, you need to use `return {requestHeaders: req.requestHeaders};`.

Comment: extra inf: http://pastebin.com/wFwDwGbn

Comment: Oh, so for 2, although I was making a new request header, I wasn't actually applying it correctly? How do I check if I sent the right request headers?

Comment: Visit `chrome://net-internals/`, go to the Events tab, (optionally) filter by youtube.com and look for "HROME_EXTENSION_MODIFIED_HEADERS".

Comment: After I put return {request header} I see it.