# Difficulty with youtube API on low bandwith

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have a YouTube player that sits in a slide of a Bootstrap carousel that sits in a template (the below doesn't include the html for the carousel):

```
<script type="text/html> <div class="video-container" id="introVideoTmpl">
 <iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Kn-7OlEVdNM?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" id="videoOne" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</script>
```

I render this by making a JavaScript call:

```
renderPageOne = function(){
var introVideoTmpl= $("#introVideoTmpl").html();
$("#container").empty();
$("#container").append(_.template(introVideoTmpl, ""));
getPlayerOne();
```

`getPlayerOne()` generates an instance of the player:

```
function getPlayerOne() {
    playerOne = new YT.Player('videoOne', {});
}
```

This `playerOne` has a `pauseVideo()` method which I call when needed.

It works fine most of the times but sometimes, with low bandwith the API seems not to load properly and the `pauseVideo()` does not work.

How can I check that the API is loaded properly so that the video can be paused when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the problem.

Problem I think was that the youtube api didn't load properly on low bandwith so avoided it all together and used the function callPlayer instead.

[YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html)