# Pause youtube video when scrolls out of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, youtube

I tried searching for the solution and yet no luck.

Problem is, I need to pause the youtube video when the video leaves `viewport` while scrolling.

I found this sample but this has video id and in my scenario, I have `iframe` so this solution isn't working on `iframe`.

Here is my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49cvf2oa/)**

Comment: In JQuery, It'll be something like: `if(window.scrollTop() > video.offset().top + video.height){ video.pause(); }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375655/youtube-video-play-pause-depend-on-visibility-of-the-frame-with-jquery I think this is what you need. Check out the answer from kosmos.

Comment: @GvM Thanks.. That helped