# get youtube playlist index

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a playlist embeded in my website using the **youtube API** (with **javascript**) and the playlist has 3 songs.

**QUESTION:** How can I get the index of the song that is currently playing?

---

**ELABORATING ON WHAT I MEAN:**

In the following snippet of code:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        loadPlaylist:{
            listType:'playlist',
            list:['1asdfasdfs','2asdfasdfs','3asdfasdfs'],
            index:parseInt(0),
            suggestedQuality:'small'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

`index:parseInt(0)` is telling the youtube api to start playing the song from the first song in the list (`1asdfasdfs`). I am assuming that this index is contantly shifting, since the users can click any of the 3 songs in the playlist and shift to another song at any time they want. What I would like is to know what method exists to get the current index.

**Note:** I recognize that I could be a bit hacky and use `player.getVideoData()['video_id'];` to retrieve the video id, and then loop through the list of three songs `['1asdfasdfs','2asdfasdfs','3asdfasdfs']` and then save the position of that video id in the array, however I believe there is a cleaner method available, possibly a method in the youtube api? I can't seem to find it anywhere though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to just use `player.getPlaylistIndex()`

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

Comment: Yup, that is what I was looking for