# How do I interact with the YouTube player on youtube.com – not the iFrame API?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I would like to receive events and get player options from a YouTube HTML5 player that is loaded when you browse to [a video page on youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4).

I know can control the player via the [HTML5 media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events). For example, when I run this code in the console, it prints `seeked` to the console whenever a seek event is triggered:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("seeked", function() { console.log("seeked") }, true);
```

However, the YouTube player offers more in its API, for example [various events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) that I want to subscribe to. How do I do that? Those events apparently are not fired on the `video` element.

For example, how can I print something on the console when the `onPlaybackQualityChange` event is fired?

Note: I am not talking about [attaching to a player loaded via the iFrame API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html).

Comment: Are you trying to get events from someone else's page (youtrube's)? How are you expecting to add your JavaScript to their page?

Comment: @Richard Through a browser extension. Not sure why someone would vote this question as being off topic — I'm not asking for a recommendation for a book, library, or off-site resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual player object that can be interacted with has the ID `movie_player`. This ID may of course change over time. As of October 2016, the ID is the same for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

For example:

```
var p = document.getElementById("movie_player");
p.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", function() { console.log("quality changed") }, true);
```

Other event listeners can of course be added according to the [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events).

The player can also be interacted with as usual:

```
p.playVideo()
```