# Retrieve YouTube video playerVars?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Is there a way in javascript to retrieve the playerVars? I don't want to change them, just be able to see how they are set.

I've Google searched and site searched every way I know, and can't find anything.

Comment: On the YouTube Iframe Player API, the talk about using getOptions, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but here's a post on SO about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html

Comment: Thanks, but way more than I need. I constructed the player, not embed it. I just want to see what 'autoplay' is set to for the player after it is constructed. Long story, but I'm using multiple players, and want to avoid keeping an array on the autoplay status. Of course, being able to see any playerVars is a bonus.