# Video runs in background upon closing modal but only for iframe elements

Tags: javascript, html

I did some research and I couldn't find this answer to this specific issue. I am displaying videos on a modal. Everything works fine when I use the "video" tag including the closing of the modal.

But when I use the "iframe" tag, upon closing the modal - the video still runs in background. Not sure what am I doing wrong.
Here is my code -

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-lg:grid-col-6 tablet:grid-col-4 margin-bottom-4">
<div class="click"><a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" aria-controls="modal--exhibit-1" data-open-modal="data-open-modal"><img src="/images/image1.jpg" class="display-block" alt="" title="" /></a></div>

<div class="usa-modal usa-modal--lg test-modal--img-gallery" id="modal--exhibit-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal--exhibit-1-heading" aria-describedby="modal--exhibit-1-description">
<div class="usa-modal__content">
<div class="usa-modal__main">


<iframe width="860" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2kJDTzFtUr4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

<button type="button" class="usa-button usa-modal__close" aria-label="Close this window" data-close-modal><svg class="usa-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img"><use xlink:href="/images/c-clamp-images/sprite.svg#close"></use></svg></button></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-lg:grid-col-6 tablet:grid-col-4 margin-bottom-4">
<div class="click"><a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" aria-controls="modal--exhibit-5" data-open-modal="data-open-modal"><img src="/images/test.jpg" class="display-block" alt="" title="" /></a></div>

<div class="usa-modal usa-modal--lg test-modal--img-gallery" id="modal--exhibit-5" aria-labelledby="modal--exhibit-5-heading" aria-describedby="modal--exhibit-5-description">
<div class="usa-modal__content">
<div class="usa-modal__main">


<video src="/test2.mp4" controls="controls" tabindex="0" alt="" title="" style=" width: 100%;"></video></div>

<button type="button" class="usa-button usa-modal__close" aria-label="Close this window" data-close-modal><svg class="usa-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img"><use xlink:href="/images/c-clamp-images/sprite.svg#close"></use></svg></button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var modal1 = document.getElementById('modal--exhibit-1');
    var modal5 = document.getElementById('modal--exhibit-5');
    
    var video1 = modal1.querySelector('video');
    var video5 = modal5.querySelector('video');
    
    var closeButton1 = modal1.querySelector('[data-close-modal]');
    var closeButton5 = modal5.querySelector('[data-close-modal]');

    closeButton1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        video1.pause();
    });

    closeButton5.addEventListener('click', function() {
        video5.pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: [YouTube iframe API: how do I control an iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7443578)