# Custom overlay controls for YouTube videos - with or without embedded iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube

I'm working on a project that contains videos from hosts like YouTube.

Is there any way to overlay my own video player controls over this kind of content?

There are various solutions that come close, but none that I've found so far will allow me to overlay my own controls over these videos.

Regarding duplicate questions: I've gone through dozens of similar questions, and I don't think there's a question or an answer that addresses this. There are many questions regarding how to embed a YouTube video, or how to control playback. My question isn't how to do either of these, but how to overlay custom controls over the YouTube video (i.e. tapping on the video brings up controls. Controls are not tacked to the bottom of the video. See Solution 1 below). It's not only about controlling the playback, but the UI that controls it. If there's a similar question that's answered and not out of date, I would love to see it.

---

**Solution 1:** Use a `video` element with `controls = {false}`, and write a hook to control playback. Tapping on the video shows the custom controls, which are overlaid on top of the `video` element.

**Outcome:** This works, but only for video formats like `.gifv` or `.mp4`. YouTube/similar content can't be used with the `video` element.

---

**Solution 2:** Convert YouTube/similar links to their embedded versions, and use the embedded link with an `iframe`.

**Outcome:** This works, but the `iframe` either has its own overlaid controls, or none at all. Custom controls cannot be overlaid over the `iframe` as far as I can tell.

---

**Solution 3:** Use a library like [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player).

**Outcome:** Similar to Solution 2. This library simply handles the embedding process for you and provides other convenience methods, but ultimately, controls cannot be overlaid on top of the `iframe`.

---

**Solution 4:** Use the [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) or a wrapper library like [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube).

**Outcome:** `iframe` playback can be controlled through this API, but controls still cannot be overlaid on top of the `iframe`. See the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hua2ge7b/1/show/) shared in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513356/3558874) answer, where controls must be set outside the `iframe`.

---

**Solution 5:** Set the `iframe` height to a portion of the screen only (e.g. 90%), and register clicks on the unused portion to show UI controls.

**Outcome:** A working but unintuitive UI whose player controls will change the instant the video is switched to fullscreen, since in fullscreen mode the `iframe` would have to be allowed to use its own controls.

---

Overall, what I've found is that it's possible to control playback of content within an `iframe`, but it isn't possible to overlay controls on top of the `iframe`.

If that's true, then is there any other way to use this kind of content within the terms of use, but without an `iframe`?

I've used mobile apps that are able to overlay their own controls on top of YouTube videos. For example, iOS apps likely use Apple's [AVKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit).

Is there anything similar for web/React?