# Stop YouTube video playing when div is closed (hidden) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a basic overlay where when a specific link is clicked content is displayed over the top of the page. This works fine but I've just added a YouTube video embed and realised when the overlay is closed the sound plays in the background. So I need to find a way to stop or pause the video. I'm inherited the code, here it is:

```
$('#size-guide a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    $('.sizeguide-popup-container').addClass('reveal');
    $('html,body').addClass('noscroll');
    $("header.mainHeader").css("position", "absolute").css("z-index", "100");
});

$(document).on("click", ".sizeguide-popup-close", function() {
    $(".sizeguide-popup-container").removeClass('reveal');
    $('html,body').removeClass('noscroll');
    $("header.mainHeader").css("position", "fixed").css("z-index", "9999999");
});

$('.sizeguide-popup-container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.sizeguide-popup-container').removeClass('reveal');
  $('html,body').removeClass('noscroll');
  $("header.mainHeader").css("position", "fixed").css("z-index", "9999999");
});
```

I guess it's just the 2nd block I need to amend but what I've tried so far hasn't done the trick. The video is automatically wrapped in a `rte__video-wrapper` div to make it responsive. So I thought I could amend it to something like the following (after reading another thread):

```
$(document).on("click", ".sizeguide-popup-close", function() {
    $(".sizeguide-popup-container").removeClass('reveal');
    $('html,body').removeClass('noscroll');
    $("header.mainHeader").css("position", "fixed").css("z-index", "9999999");
    $(".rte__video-wrapper iframe").attr('src','');
});
```

As that essentially just removes the videos link so when the overlay is reopened there's a big blank space. Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

According to the iframe API, you can stop a youtube video using [player.stopVideo()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

> **player.stopVideo():Void** Stops and cancels loading of the current video. This function should be reserved for rare situations when you
>   know that the user will not be watching additional video in the
>   player. If your intent is to pause the video, you should just call the
>   pauseVideo function. If you want to change the video that the player
>   is playing, you can call one of the queueing functions without calling
>   stopVideo first.

You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671232/youtube-api-stop-video) for additional code reference.